# Track one prop with useEffect that depends on multiple props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There is a code that looks like this:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({
    trackMyChanges,
    iChangeEverySecond
}) => 
{
    // React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'iChangeEverySecond'
    useEffect(() => {
        calculateData(trackMyChanges, iChangeEverySecond);
    }, [trackMyChanges]);   
    
    return <> ... </>;
}
```

The code executes `calculateData` in case the `trackMyChanges` prop have been changed. It works ok, but I get a warning that `iChangeEverySecond` dependency is missing. I don't want the hook to run because `iChangeEverySecond` have been changed, though. What is the proper way to handle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the useCallback hook to solving this:

```
const calculateData = useCallback(() => {
  console.log(iChangeEverySecond);
}, [iChangeEverySecond]);

useEffect(() => {
  calculateData(trackMyChanges);
}, [trackMyChanges, calculateData]);
```

So every time your iChangeEverySecond changes, it will redefine your calculateData function to be the most updated version of it, but it will be triggered only when trackMyChanges changed.

Comment: I've ended up using useMemoizedCallback hook. It updates the function right before execution.

Comment: I'm glad you could found a solution. I'll definitely read more about this useMemoizedCallback

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the scope. You have tu understand that, the array is an element that helps the `useEffect` to update the props or the state used inside the anonymous function. In your case `iChangeEverySecond` is props, so it "should", not necessarily be in the array because is being used inside the function.

I leave you a complete explanation extracted from the react website.

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values
>   from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over
>   time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will
>   reference stale values from previous renders. Learn more about how to
>   deal with functions and what to do when the array values change too
>   often.
>
> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
>   unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
>   tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
>   or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
>   case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
>   works.
>
> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect
>   will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second
>   argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and
>   componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions
>   to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React
>   defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing
>   extra work is less of a problem.
>
> We recommend using the exhaustive-deps rule as part of our
>   eslint-plugin-react-hooks package. It warns when dependencies are
>   specified incorrectly and suggests a fix.

Comment: Oh, sorry for being unclear. I do know the way the useEffect hook works and I totally understand the reason why the warning appeared. I'm looking for the best way to handle this case. There might be a better solution than just excluding a value from the dependencies array.

Comment: @HirasawaYui is the ```calculateData(trackMyChanges, iChangeEverySecond)```  function defined inside ```MyComponent```

Comment: Yes, it's defined inside MyComponent.

Answer (score -1):

This is because **iChangeEverySecond** run each time when **trackMyChanges**. changed. To handle this scenerio you can add **ichangeEverySecond** in localstorage when it initially load and then fetch it in useEffect each time when **trackMyChanges** changed.

localStorage.setItem("iChangeEverySecond", iChangeEverySecond)

useEffect(() => {

```
    calculateData(trackMyChanges, localStorage.getItem(iChangeEverySecond));
}, [trackMyChanges]);
```